# access static html page from jar file using spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jar

I want to call home.html file present in jar under /WEB-INF/lib using spring.

Below is configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.barclays.mobile.gateway.controller")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Bean(name = "viewResolver")
public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addResourceHandler("/component/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/app/component/*");
   registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/app/assets/*");
   registry.addResourceHandler("/home/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/app/*");
}

}
```

Below is controller:

```
@Controller
public class StaffController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home() {
    return "home";
}
}
```

Please suggest how to do this.?

Comment: Try with `return "lib/home";`.

Answer (score 0):

remove `/` from `/home`,  I guess that is the problem